# Реализовать переиспользованый компонент?

Tags: vue.js, vue3

Рад любой имеи
Как реализовать компонент который может принимать картинку (картинка может быть любой), title, description. Главное чтобы компонент мог переиспользоваться (разная картика, title, description )

Comment: Объявляйте props и передавайте в компонент что хотите... Подробнее в документации.

Comment: напишите код пожалуйста, Реализация вашей идеи. Более не ясно как передать текст

Comment: Читайте документацию! https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-props.html

Comment: да верно - проблема решена. Путем :title=" 'Title 1' " . Не знал что там можно делать